# Pure CSS interactive human body

Tags: css

I am trying to create a human body, that shows on click a belonging section. Currently this is done via Javascript and for testing its just the name of the belonging body part.

I wondering if there is a way to do this interactive human body with css only? Any idea to achive that?

```js
window.onload = function () {
    const pieces = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    for (var i = 0; pieces.length; i++) {
        let _piece = pieces[i];
        _piece.onclick = function(t) {
            if (t.target.getAttribute('data-position') != null) document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.getAttribute('data-position');
            if (t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position') != null) document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.human-body {
    width: 207px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 240px;
    height: 260px;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
.human-body svg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.human-body svg:hover path {
    fill: #ff7d16;
}
.human-body svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    fill: #57c9d5;
}
.human-body svg.head {
    margin-left: -28.5px;
    top: -6px;
}
.human-body svg.shoulder {
    margin-left: -53.5px;
    top: 69px;
}
.human-body svg.arm {
    margin-left: -78px;
    top: 112px;
}
.human-body svg.cheast {
    margin-left: -43.5px;
    top: 88px;
}
.human-body svg.stomach {
    margin-left: -37.5px;
    top: 130px;
}
.human-body svg.legs {
    margin-left: -46.5px;
    top: 205px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.human-body svg.hands {
    margin-left: -102.5px;
    top: 224px;
}
#area {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="human-body">
        <svg data-position="head" class="head" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56.594" height="95.031" viewBox="0 0 56.594 95.031"><path d="M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848zm6.11-27.775l.108-11.775-21.16-14.742L8.123 26.133 8.09 40.19l-3.24.215 1.462 9.732 5.208 1.81 2.36 11.63 9.72 11.018 10.856-.324 9.56-10.37 1.918-11.952 5.207-1.81 1.342-9.517zm-43.085-1.84l-.257-13.82L28.226 11.9l23.618 15.755-.216 10.37 4.976-17.085L42.556 2.376 25.49 0 10.803 3.673.002 24.415z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="shoulder" class="shoulder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="109.532" height="46.594" viewBox="0 0 109.532 46.594"><path d="M38.244-.004l1.98 9.232-11.653 2.857-7.474-2.637zm33.032 0l-1.98 9.232 11.653 2.857 7.474-2.637zm21.238 10.54l4.044-2.187 12.656 14 .07 5.33S92.76 10.66 92.515 10.535zm-1.285.58c-.008.28 17.762 18.922 17.762 18.922l.537 16.557-6.157-10.55L91.5 30.988 83.148 15.6zm-74.224-.58L12.962 8.35l-12.656 14-.062 5.325s16.52-17.015 16.764-17.14zm1.285.58C18.3 11.396.528 30.038.528 30.038L-.01 46.595l6.157-10.55 11.87-5.056L26.374 15.6z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="arm" class="arm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="156.344" height="119.25" viewBox="0 0 156.344 119.25"><path d="M21.12 56.5a1.678 1.678 0 0 1-.427.33l.935 8.224 12.977-13.89 1.2-8.958A168.2 168.2 0 0 0 21.12 56.5zm1.387 12.522l-18.07 48.91 5.757 1.333 19.125-39.44 3.518-22.047zm-5.278-18.96l2.638 18.74-17.2 46.023L.01 113.05l6.644-35.518zm118.015 6.44a1.678 1.678 0 0 0 .426.33l-.934 8.222-12.977-13.89-1.2-8.958A168.2 168.2 0 0 1 135.24 56.5zm-1.39 12.52l18.073 48.91-5.758 1.333-19.132-39.44-3.52-22.05zm5.28-18.96l-2.64 18.74 17.2 46.023 2.658-1.775-6.643-35.518zm-103.1-12.323a1.78 1.78 0 0 1 .407-.24l3.666-27.345L33.07.015l-7.258 10.58-6.16 37.04.566 4.973a151.447 151.447 0 0 1 15.808-14.87zm84.3 0a1.824 1.824 0 0 0-.407-.24l-3.666-27.345L123.3.015l7.258 10.58 6.16 37.04-.566 4.973a151.447 151.447 0 0 0-15.822-14.87zM22.288 8.832l-3.3 35.276-2.2-26.238zm111.79 0l3.3 35.276 2.2-26.238z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="cheast" class="cheast" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="86.594" height="45.063" viewBox="0 0 86.594 45.063"><path d="M19.32 0l-9.225 16.488-10.1 5.056 6.15 4.836 4.832 14.07 11.2 4.616 17.85-8.828-4.452-34.7zm47.934 0l9.225 16.488 10.1 5.056-6.15 4.836-4.833 14.07-11.2 4.616-17.844-8.828 4.45-34.7z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="stomach" class="stomach" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75.25" height="107.594" viewBox="0 0 75.25 107.594"><path d="M19.25 7.49l16.6-7.5-.5 12.16-14.943 7.662zm-10.322 8.9l6.9 3.848-.8-9.116zm5.617-8.732L1.32 2.15 6.3 15.6zm-8.17 9.267l9.015 5.514 1.54 11.028-8.795-5.735zm15.53 5.89l.332 8.662 12.286-2.665.664-11.826zm14.61 84.783L33.28 76.062l-.08-20.53-11.654-5.736-1.32 37.5zM22.735 35.64L22.57 46.3l11.787 3.166.166-16.657zm-14.16-5.255L16.49 35.9l1.1 11.25-8.8-7.06zm8.79 22.74l-9.673-7.28-.84 9.78L-.006 68.29l10.564 14.594 5.5.883 1.98-20.735zM56 7.488l-16.6-7.5.5 12.16 14.942 7.66zm10.32 8.9l-6.9 3.847.8-9.116zm-5.617-8.733L73.93 2.148l-4.98 13.447zm8.17 9.267l-9.015 5.514-1.54 11.03 8.8-5.736zm-15.53 5.89l-.332 8.662-12.285-2.665-.664-11.827zm-14.61 84.783l3.234-31.536.082-20.532 11.65-5.735 1.32 37.5zm13.78-71.957l.166 10.66-11.786 3.168-.166-16.657zm14.16-5.256l-7.915 5.514-1.1 11.25 8.794-7.06zm-8.79 22.743l9.673-7.28.84 9.78 6.862 12.66-10.564 14.597-5.5.883-1.975-20.74z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="legs" class="legs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="93.626" height="286.625" viewBox="0 0 93.626 286.625"><path d="M17.143 138.643l-.664 5.99 4.647 5.77 1.55 9.1 3.1 1.33 2.655-13.755 1.77-4.88-1.55-3.107zm20.582.444l-3.32 9.318-7.082 13.755 1.77 12.647 5.09-14.2 4.205-7.982zm-26.557-12.645l5.09 27.29-3.32-1.777-2.656 8.875zm22.795 42.374l-1.55 4.88-3.32 20.634-.442 27.51 4.65 26.847-.223-34.39 4.87-13.754.663-15.087zM23.34 181.24l1.106 41.267 8.853 33.28-9.628-4.55-16.045-57.8 5.533-36.384zm15.934 80.536l-.664 18.415-1.55 6.435h-4.647l-1.327-4.437-1.55-.222.332 4.437-5.864-1.778-1.55-.887-6.64-1.442-.22-5.214 6.418-10.87 4.426-5.548 10.844-4.437zM13.63 3.076v22.476l15.71 31.073 9.923 30.85L38.23 66.1zm25.49 30.248l.118-.148-.793-2.024L21.9 12.992l-1.242-.44L31.642 40.93zM32.865 44.09l6.812 17.6 2.274-21.596-1.344-3.43zM6.395 61.91l.827 25.34 12.816 35.257-3.928 10.136L3.5 88.133zM30.96 74.69l.345.826 6.47 15.48-4.177 38.342-6.594-3.526 5.715-35.7zm45.5 63.953l.663 5.99-4.647 5.77-1.55 9.1-3.1 1.33-2.655-13.755-1.77-4.88 1.55-3.107zm-20.582.444l3.32 9.318 7.08 13.755-1.77 12.647-5.09-14.2-4.2-7.987zm3.762 29.73l1.55 4.88 3.32 20.633.442 27.51-4.648 26.847.22-34.39-4.867-13.754-.67-15.087zm10.623 12.424l-1.107 41.267-8.852 33.28 9.627-4.55 16.046-57.8-5.533-36.384zM54.33 261.777l.663 18.415 1.546 6.435h4.648l1.328-4.437 1.55-.222-.333 4.437 5.863-1.778 1.55-.887 6.638-1.442.222-5.214-6.418-10.868-4.426-5.547-10.844-4.437zm25.643-258.7v22.476L64.26 56.625l-9.923 30.85L55.37 66.1zM54.48 33.326l-.118-.15.793-2.023L71.7 12.993l1.24-.44L61.96 40.93zm6.255 10.764l-6.812 17.6-2.274-21.595 1.344-3.43zm26.47 17.82l-.827 25.342-12.816 35.256 3.927 10.136 12.61-44.51zM62.64 74.693l-.346.825-6.47 15.48 4.178 38.342 6.594-3.527-5.715-35.7zm19.792 51.75l-5.09 27.29 3.32-1.776 2.655 8.875zM9.495-.007l.827 21.373-7.028 42.308-3.306-34.155zm2.068 27.323L26.24 59.707l3.307 26-6.2 36.58L9.91 85.046l-.827-38.342zM84.103-.01l-.826 21.375 7.03 42.308 3.306-34.155zm-2.066 27.325L67.36 59.707l-3.308 26 6.2 36.58 13.436-37.24.827-38.34z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="hands" class="hands" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="205" height="38.938" viewBox="0 0 205 38.938"><path d="M21.255-.002l2.88 6.9 8.412 1.335.664 12.458-4.427 17.8-2.878-.22 2.8-11.847-2.99-.084-4.676 12.6-3.544-.446 4.4-12.736-3.072-.584-5.978 13.543-4.428-.445 6.088-14.1-2.1-1.25-7.528 12.012-3.764-.445L12.4 12.9l-1.107-1.78L.665 15.57 0 13.124l8.635-7.786zm162.49 0l-2.88 6.9-8.412 1.335-.664 12.458 4.427 17.8 2.878-.22-2.8-11.847 2.99-.084 4.676 12.6 3.544-.446-4.4-12.736 3.072-.584 5.978 13.543 4.428-.445-6.088-14.1 2.1-1.25 7.528 12.012 3.764-.445L192.6 12.9l1.107-1.78 10.628 4.45.665-2.447-8.635-7.786z"/></svg>
    </div>

    <div id="area">
        Area: <span id="data"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, am I allowed to use this code for my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you can create something like this with :active state? just my first idea

```css
p {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  background-color: #fff;
  
  display: none;
}

p:target {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#head">
  <svg data-position="head" class="head" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56.594" height="95.031" viewBox="0 0 56.594 95.031"><path d="M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848zm6.11-27.775l.108-11.775-21.16-14.742L8.123 26.133 8.09 40.19l-3.24.215 1.462 9.732 5.208 1.81 2.36 11.63 9.72 11.018 10.856-.324 9.56-10.37 1.918-11.952 5.207-1.81 1.342-9.517zm-43.085-1.84l-.257-13.82L28.226 11.9l23.618 15.755-.216 10.37 4.976-17.085L42.556 2.376 25.49 0 10.803 3.673.002 24.415z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a href="#shoulder">
  <svg data-position="shoulder" class="shoulder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="109.532" height="46.594" viewBox="0 0 109.532 46.594"><path d="M38.244-.004l1.98 9.232-11.653 2.857-7.474-2.637zm33.032 0l-1.98 9.232 11.653 2.857 7.474-2.637zm21.238 10.54l4.044-2.187 12.656 14 .07 5.33S92.76 10.66 92.515 10.535zm-1.285.58c-.008.28 17.762 18.922 17.762 18.922l.537 16.557-6.157-10.55L91.5 30.988 83.148 15.6zm-74.224-.58L12.962 8.35l-12.656 14-.062 5.325s16.52-17.015 16.764-17.14zm1.285.58C18.3 11.396.528 30.038.528 30.038L-.01 46.595l6.157-10.55 11.87-5.056L26.374 15.6z"/></svg></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="area">
  <p id="head">Head</p>
  <p id="shoulder">Shoulder</p>
```

Comment: or even better you can use :target and place the text elements wherever you want. then you can link `<a href="#head"><svg... /></a><div class="area"><p id="target">Head</p></div>`

Comment: may I ask you to update your code with this? I am not getting it

Comment: yes, i updated the code. Hope it helps to clarify the idea

Answer (score 4):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    data_clicked_id: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    part_clicked(val) {
      this.data_clicked_id = val.target.getAttribute('id')
      console.log(val.target.getAttribute('id'))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.human-body {
  width: 207px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.human-body svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.human-body svg path:hover {
  fill: #a80000;
}

.human-body svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  fill: #000;
}


#area #data {
  color: black;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="human-body">
    <svg @click="part_clicked" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         width="259.22897"
   height="350"
   viewBox="0 0 68.587668 92.604164"
         >
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 11.671635,6.3585449 -0.0482,-2.59085 4.20648,-2.46806 4.42769,2.95361 -0.0405,1.94408 0.24197,-3.34467 -2.03129,-2.31103004 -2.84508,-0.51629 -2.20423,0.52915 -1.9363,2.63077004 z"
     id="head" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 19.748825,6.7034949 0.0203,-2.20747 -3.96689,-2.7637 -3.74099,2.23559 -0.006,2.63528 -0.60741,0.0403 0.27408,1.82447 0.97635,0.33932 0.44244,2.1802901 1.82222,2.06556 2.03518,-0.0607 1.79223,-1.94408 0.35957,-2.2406601 0.97616,-0.33932 0.25159,-1.78416 z"
     id="face" />
  <path
     id="neck"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 13.304665,11.910505 1.64975,2.35202 0.74426,2.62159 -1.73486,-1.38354 -0.86649,-2.97104 z m 5.08047,0 -1.64975,2.35202 -0.74538,2.62234 1.73486,-1.38354 0.86649,-2.97104 z" />
  <path
     id="shoulder-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 19.047795,13.248365 3.55748,1.97916 0.72653,-0.35074 z m -0.107,0.43288 -0.37119,1.73073 2.1846,0.53561 1.40116,-0.49436 z m 3.98151,1.97595 0.75814,-0.41 2.40806,1.66799 1.17364,1.50707 0.62662,1.5626 -0.0464,3.70194 -1.3284,-1.72153 0.0407,-2.59376 -0.48842,-0.50049 c 0,0 -3.09778,-3.19058 -3.14371,-3.21401 z m -0.2409,0.10873 c -0.001,0.0525 3.32987,3.54733 3.32987,3.54733 l 0.10067,3.10396 -1.15426,-1.97782 -2.22547,-0.94804 -1.56576,-2.88481 z" />
  <path
     id="shoulder-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 12.624785,13.248365 -3.5574599,1.97916 -0.72653,-0.35074 z m 0.107,0.43288 0.37119,1.73073 -2.18459,0.53561 -1.4011499,-0.49436 z m -3.9814899,1.97595 -0.75814,-0.41 -2.40806,1.66799 -1.17364,1.50707 -0.62662,1.56259 0.0464,3.70195 1.3284,-1.72153 -0.0407,-2.59376 0.48843,-0.5005 c 0,0 3.09777,-3.19057 3.1437,-3.214 z m 0.2409,0.10873 c 0.002,0.0525 -3.32987,3.54733 -3.32987,3.54733 l -0.10067,3.10396 1.15426,-1.97782 2.22547,-0.94804 1.5657499,-2.88481 z" />
  <path
     id="arm-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 27.621665,30.814715 -0.33838,1.70499 -1.81932,-2.54418 -0.6629,-1.26895 z m -2.85271,-2.6096 c -0.0259,-0.0144 -0.0536,-0.0254 -0.0824,-0.0324 l -1.48333,-4.95503 1.00456,-2.08428 1.65511,1.74532 2.23034,6.67667 0.0415,0.93739 c -1.06528,-0.84215 -2.18962,-1.60679 -3.36434,-2.28803 z m 1.6945,-5.75654 1.64893,6.43421 -0.36469,-4.92266 z" />
  <path
     id="forearm-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 26.955425,32.969125 1.30083,10.28927 -1.10778,0.01 -1.89387,-7.99609 0.19174,-4.53719 z m 1.21978,-1.94971 -0.58729,2.58635 1.11876,9.15614 0.55849,-0.21663 0.2304,-6.77018 z" />
  <path
     id="arm-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 4.0746451,30.814715 0.33838,1.70499 1.81931,-2.54418 0.66289,-1.26895 z m 2.8527,-2.6096 c 0.0259,-0.0144 0.0536,-0.0254 0.0824,-0.0324 l 1.48332,-4.95503 -1.00455,-2.08428 -1.65509,1.74532 -2.23034,6.67667 -0.0415,0.93739 c 1.06528,-0.84215 2.18961,-1.60679 3.36433,-2.28803 z m -1.6945,-5.75654 -1.64891,6.43421 0.36468,-4.92266 z" />
  <path
     id="forearm-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 4.5752651,32.969125 -1.30083,10.28927 1.10778,0.01 1.89387,-7.99609 -0.19174,-4.53719 z m -1.21978,-1.94971 0.58728,2.58635 -1.11875,9.15614 -0.55849,-0.21663 -0.2304,-6.77018 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 20.337455,17.085495 1.72942,3.09103 1.89346,0.94785 -1.15295,0.90662 -0.90604,2.63773 -2.09968,0.86537 -3.34524,-1.655 0.83425,-6.50527 z"
     id="chest-left" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 11.351215,17.085495 -1.7294199,3.09103 -1.89346,0.94785 1.15295,0.90662 0.90586,2.63773 2.0996699,0.86537 3.34636,-1.655 -0.83462,-6.50527 z"
     id="chest-right" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 19.641935,34.707615 1.81341,-1.36479 0.15748,1.83347 1.28642,2.37338 -1.98044,2.73652 -1.03109,0.16554 -0.37026,-3.88816 z"
     id="belly-left" />
  <path
     id="ribs-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 19.288925,26.151995 -3.11202,-1.40604 0.0937,2.27965 2.80119,1.43603 z m 1.93471,1.66849 -1.29355,0.7212 0.14997,-1.70898 z m -1.05303,-1.63718 2.47968,-1.03241 -0.9336,2.52093 z m 1.53164,1.73729 -1.69005,1.03372 -0.28871,2.0678 1.64975,-1.07533 z m -2.91143,1.10421 -0.0622,1.62387 -2.30308,-0.49961 -0.12448,-2.21722 z m -0.1556,2.4045 0.0311,1.99844 -2.20953,0.59391 -0.0311,-3.1227 z m 2.65459,-0.98535 -1.48383,1.03372 -0.20622,2.10905 1.64862,-1.32355 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 12.045985,34.707615 -1.81341,-1.36479 -0.15748,1.83347 -1.2856799,2.37432 1.9804499,2.73595 1.03109,0.16554 0.37119,-3.88721 z"
     id="belly-right" />
  <path
     id="belly"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 15.636055,44.919735 -0.60647,-5.91209 -0.015,-3.84879 -2.18479,-1.07533 -0.24746,7.03017 z m 0.41581,-5.7e-4 0.60628,-5.91209 0.0154,-3.84915 2.18404,-1.07515 0.24746,7.03017 z" />
  <path
     id="ribs-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 12.399365,26.152365 3.11202,-1.40603 -0.0937,2.27965 -2.80138,1.4364 z m -1.93508,1.6685 1.29355,0.72139 -0.14997,-1.70899 z m 1.05303,-1.637 -2.4793099,-1.03259 0.93361,2.52148 z m -1.5316399,1.73729 1.6900499,1.03372 0.28871,2.06743 -1.64881,-1.07515 z m 2.9114199,1.10421 0.0623,1.62387 2.30327,-0.49961 0.12448,-2.21703 z m 0.15561,2.40432 -0.0309,1.99844 2.20973,0.59353 0.0311,-3.1227 z m -2.6546,-0.98516 1.48384,1.0339 0.20622,2.10905 -1.64975,-1.32355 z" />
  <path
     id="thigh-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 23.419015,50.399125 -0.15504,4.75091 -2.40263,6.60949 0.7362,1.90021 2.36401,-8.34435 z m -0.58154,-11.60825 -0.15485,4.00722 1.31793,7.93154 0.61977,-6.40308 z m -0.38731,5.12268 -2.75152,6.07258 -0.62015,4.87425 1.16232,6.85771 2.51886,-6.98144 0.15504,-7.18764 z" />
  <path
     id="innerthigh-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 22.063225,39.369605 v 4.21363 l -2.94574,5.82511 -1.86027,5.78349 0.19365,-4.0072 z m -3.24944,13.42596 -0.0649,0.15467 -1.21294,2.90207 0.78325,7.18803 1.23619,-0.66122 -1.0714,-6.69272 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 17.255895,87.868445 0.1243,3.45228 0.28983,1.20638 h 0.87136 l 0.24897,-0.83181 0.29058,-0.0416 -0.0624,0.83181 1.09914,-0.33332 0.29058,-0.16629 1.24444,-0.27033 0.0416,-0.97748 -1.20319,-2.03743 -0.82974,-1.0399 -2.03294,-0.83181 z"
     id="feet-left" />
  <path
     id="calf-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 18.251375,70.441125 0.29058,0.91486 0.6224,3.8681 0.0829,5.15733 -0.87136,5.03304 0.0412,-6.44714 -0.91242,-2.57848 -0.12561,-2.82837 z m 1.9915,2.32915 -0.20753,7.73637 -1.65949,6.23904 1.80478,-0.853 3.00816,-10.83583 -1.03727,-6.82095 z" />
  <path
     id="knee-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 21.404635,64.784375 0.1243,1.12295 -0.87118,1.08171 -0.29058,1.70599 -0.58116,0.24933 -0.49774,-2.57866 -0.33182,-0.91486 0.29058,-0.58247 z m -3.85853,0.0832 0.6224,1.74685 1.3273,2.57867 -0.33182,2.37095 -0.95423,-2.66209 -0.78738,-1.49734 z m 4.97811,-2.37039 -0.95423,5.11609 0.62241,-0.33295 0.49773,1.66381 z" />
  <path
     id="thigh-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 8.2694651,50.399125 0.15504,4.75053 2.4026299,6.60968 -0.73638,1.90021 -2.3640099,-8.34435 z m 0.58117,-11.60768 0.15503,4.00684 -1.31754,7.93154 -0.61978,-6.40308 z m 0.38769,5.1223 2.7515099,6.07239 0.61997,4.87425 -1.16232,6.85771 -2.5190499,-6.98163 -0.15504,-7.18801 z" />
  <path
     id="genitalia"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 14.404465,45.040075 0.0221,-0.0277 -0.14866,-0.37945 -3.10172,-3.40449 -0.23283,-0.0825 2.05918,5.32009 z m -1.17263,2.01833 1.27705,3.29948 0.42631,-4.04862 -0.25196,-0.64303 z m 4.05219,-2.01795 -0.0221,-0.0281 0.14867,-0.37926 3.10171,-3.40449 0.23246,-0.0825 -2.05843,5.3199 z m 1.17263,2.01795 -1.27706,3.29948 -0.42631,-4.04843 0.25197,-0.64303 z" />
  <path
     id="innerthigh-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 9.6258251,39.369415 v 4.21363 l 2.9451699,5.8253 1.86028,5.78349 -0.19366,-4.0072 z m 3.2488699,13.42559 0.0647,0.15485 1.21294,2.90207 -0.78307,7.18803 -1.23618,-0.66102 1.0714,-6.69273 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 14.433335,87.868265 -0.12448,3.45228 -0.29058,1.20637 h -0.87118 l -0.24877,-0.83181 -0.29059,-0.0416 0.0623,0.83181 -1.09934,-0.33333 -0.29058,-0.16629 -1.2448,-0.27033 -0.0412,-0.97747 1.2031899,-2.03781 0.82975,-1.04009 2.03294,-0.83181 z"
     id="right-feet" />
  <path
     id="calf-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 13.437675,70.440945 -0.29058,0.91486 -0.62241,3.86828 -0.0829,5.15733 0.87174,5.03304 -0.0418,-6.44714 0.91298,-2.57848 0.1243,-2.82837 z m -1.99151,2.32914 0.20735,7.73637 1.65968,6.23904 -1.80497,-0.85299 -3.0079799,-10.83584 1.03728,-6.82095 z" />
  <path
     id="knee-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 10.284405,64.784375 -0.12448,1.12295 0.87118,1.08171 0.29058,1.70599 0.58116,0.24933 0.49774,-2.57866 0.33182,-0.91486 -0.29058,-0.58247 z m 3.85854,0.0832 -0.62241,1.74685 -1.32767,2.57867 0.33182,2.37095 0.95423,-2.66209 0.78832,-1.4964 z m -4.9786799,-2.37058 0.9542299,5.11609 -0.6223999,-0.33313 -0.49793,1.6638 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 3.2054751,27.370125 0.005,3.09419 -0.57959,1.91184 -0.54539,-2.41185 z"
     id="elbow-right" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 4.3904451,43.563145 -1.5198,0.0506 -0.76631,-0.67112 -1.21261996,2.15767 -0.86245,3.32873 0.49386,0.22113 0.59814996,-2.20238 0.50016,0.25356 -0.35639,2.49422 0.62382,0.24345 0.41402,-2.49194 0.55839,0.17851 -0.2262,2.76603 0.76938,0.32268 0.25788,-2.86764 0.4578,-0.0181 0.16611,2.65239 0.65997,0.2633 0.0712,-4.56643 0.34158,-0.19428 1.35316,1.68367 0.32832,-0.34354 -0.72644,-2.0551 z"
     id="hand-right" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 28.325215,27.370125 -0.005,3.09419 0.57959,1.91184 0.54538,-2.41185 z"
     id="elbow-left" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 27.140245,43.563145 1.5198,0.0506 0.76631,-0.67111 1.21262,2.15766 0.86245,3.32873 -0.49386,0.22113 -0.59815,-2.20238 -0.50016,0.25356 0.35639,2.49422 -0.62382,0.24345 -0.41402,-2.49194 -0.55839,0.17851 0.2262,2.76603 -0.76938,0.32268 -0.25788,-2.86764 -0.4578,-0.0181 -0.16611,2.6524 -0.65997,0.26329 -0.0712,-4.56643 -0.34158,-0.19428 -1.35316,1.68368 -0.32832,-0.34355 0.72644,-2.0551 z"
     id="hands-left" />
  <path
     id="armback-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 43.185645,27.069445 0.4297,-1.4164 1.30458,-1.68577 -1.39393,-2.96155 -2.28367,0.92162 -1.83567,1.7467 -0.53524,1.78673 0.27068,4.30806 z m -2.46869,15.35539 -1.5182,0.0863 -0.78184,-0.65295 -1.16168,2.1855 -0.78414,3.34805 0.49892,0.20949 0.54632,-2.2158 0.50597,0.24175 -0.29779,2.5019 0.62936,0.22875 0.35546,-2.50096 0.56242,0.16536 -0.16126,2.77057 0.77674,0.30455 0.19056,-2.87291 0.45724,-0.0289 0.22827,2.64778 0.66597,0.24774 -0.0359,-4.56685 0.33693,-0.20224 1.39227,1.65147 0.32017,-0.35115 -0.77444,-2.03749 z m -0.97726,-0.17765 -1.43509,-0.746 -0.30622,-7.00985 c 0,0 0.64359,-2.77938 0.63694,-3.06274 l 0.6093,-1.21924 3.62552,-2.56583 -0.68276,1.9919 0.41561,4.74788 -1.80402,7.69727 z" />
  <path
     id="leg-left"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 51.176145,64.073985 -1.20605,3.01461 0.70738,0.26558 0.89754,3.51771 -0.55801,-4.01191 z m -5.08496,-3.15003 0.63355,1.8609 0.16813,2.03261 0.61314,1.93117 -0.90585,-0.0851 -0.28534,2.15982 z m 4.3014,6.58834 1.27664,4.99697 -0.28984,3.02284 -0.67869,10.06546 -1.66325,0.63506 -3.50399,-11.96959 1.24985,-7.17525 z m 0.54053,20.8287 0.85194,1.3581 0.37189,0.79238 -0.15588,1.21774 -0.76984,0.74446 -1.51185,0.12543 -1.1299,-0.29192 -0.24225,-0.95894 0.80765,-1.30405 -0.22562,-0.85987 0.29679,-0.84153 -0.0194,-1.81524 1.53568,-0.54817 z m -1.19598,0.4675 0.15943,1.25776 -0.6023,0.97431 m -0.54436,0.29544 1.06474,0.40084 1.55326,-0.65137 m -4.19331,-39.53466 4.55099,-2.03879 0.63802,0.23079 0.0353,1.80672 0.075,4.64669 -1.97837,6.04282 0.47612,1.41403 -1.42812,3.29446 -1.76611,-0.30111 -0.50079,-2.11605 -0.1695,-1.75674 -2.42102,-8.15763 -0.34279,-3.64687 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 44.742845,39.689035 5.48374,1.86457 2.27386,1.3378 2.74195,-1.74412 4.51804,-1.28077 0.90009,2.29721 0.675,3.4346 -0.81272,5.02838 -2.82636,0.16819 -4.11256,-1.67581 -1.00814,0.39118 -0.95849,-0.39888 -4.44053,1.94411 -2.77023,-0.51478 -0.95181,-6.15325 0.36754,-2.7864 z"
     id="buttock" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 51.818445,37.309575 0.14418,2.97292 1.15984,-0.0241 0.048,-2.96488 2.80867,-0.81981 2.34029,-0.7541 1.34121,3.73319 -4.77886,1.36455 -2.33301,1.2158 -2.37536,-1.2333 -5.45663,-1.37716 1.51961,-3.95743 z"
     id="loin" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 51.733705,14.788555 0.53876,25.33066 0.48967,-0.0297 0.65658,-25.3387 -0.28147,-0.84188 -1.25059,-4.9e-4 z"
     id="column" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 48.157455,6.3585449 0.44208,-0.14964 0.16111,0.16427 1.48163,4.0475101 2.32401,1.45118 2.39971,-1.52387 0.97577,-3.6896901 0.52752,-0.55908 0.23367,0.0981 0.24198,-3.34467 -2.03129,-2.31103004 -2.84509,-0.51629 -2.20422,0.52915 -1.93631,2.63077004 z"
     id="head-back" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 52.369695,12.105075 -2.35767,-1.55045 -1.47119,-3.9514301 -0.60741,0.0403 0.27409,1.82447 0.97635,0.33932 0.7613,2.2157201 0.33017,1.06849 0.0895,2.14894 1.16448,0.008 0.10563,-0.70833 0.54716,-0.0606 z m 1.01793,1.47595 0.23768,0.64982 1.38107,-0.004 0.01,-2.38784 0.25971,-0.79061 0.57215,-2.1698001 0.76359,-0.41018 0.25158,-1.78416 -0.62859,0.0193 -1.08488,3.8998101 -2.39725,1.46684 0.2768,1.48507 z"
     id="nape" />
  <path
     id="armback-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 61.657445,27.250625 -0.32785,-1.05121 -1.27383,-2.05489 1.38708,-2.96476 2.28579,0.91634 1.83971,1.74245 0.53937,1.78549 -0.26073,4.30868 z m 2.64394,15.3417 1.51839,0.0828 0.78033,-0.65476 1.16673,2.18281 0.79187,3.34623 -0.49843,0.21064 -0.55144,-2.21453 -0.50541,0.24292 0.30356,2.5012 -0.62882,0.23021 -0.36124,-2.50014 -0.56203,0.16666 0.16765,2.77019 -0.77603,0.30634 -0.19719,-2.87245 -0.45732,-0.0278 -0.22215,2.64829 -0.66539,0.24928 0.0254,-4.56692 -0.3374,-0.20146 -1.38845,1.65469 -0.32098,-0.35041 0.76973,-2.03928 z m 0.97685,-0.1799 1.43335,-0.74932 0.29002,-7.01054 c 0,0 -0.65,-2.77789 -0.64401,-3.06126 l -0.61212,-1.21783 -3.98124,-2.57566 1.0222,1.93525 -0.38967,4.82212 1.8218,7.69308 z" />
  <path
     id="leg-right"
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 54.019305,64.073985 1.20605,3.01461 -0.70737,0.26558 -0.89755,3.51771 0.55802,-4.01191 z m 5.08496,-3.15003 -0.63355,1.8609 -0.16813,2.03261 -0.61313,1.93117 0.90584,-0.0851 0.28534,2.15982 z m -4.3014,6.58834 -1.27664,4.99697 0.28984,3.02284 0.67869,10.06546 1.66325,0.63506 3.504,-11.96959 -1.24986,-7.17525 z m -0.54053,20.8287 -0.85194,1.3581 -0.37189,0.79238 0.15589,1.21774 0.76983,0.74446 1.51186,0.12543 1.12989,-0.29192 0.24225,-0.95894 -0.80765,-1.30405 0.22563,-0.85987 -0.29679,-0.84153 0.0194,-1.81524 -1.53568,-0.54817 z m 1.19598,0.4675 -0.15943,1.25776 0.6023,0.97431 m 0.54436,0.29544 -1.06474,0.40084 -1.55326,-0.65137 m 3.56525,-39.90247 -3.97962,-1.70224 -0.56389,0.27131 -0.0528,1.79746 -0.075,4.64669 1.97837,6.04282 -0.47612,1.41403 1.42813,3.29446 1.7661,-0.30111 0.50079,-2.11605 0.1695,-1.75674 2.42102,-8.15763 0.009,-3.68308 z" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 62.863315,16.685695 1.57473,1.56518 0.81404,2.06904 0.0384,2.52859 -1.48921,-1.23926 -2.76223,-1.15539 -1.84691,3.4342 -1.13679,5.49715 -0.0767,5.8593 -4.07066,1.10938 0.10355,-7.94098 1.94107,-4.90021 5.04395,-8.19335 z"
     id="back-right" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 55.439085,14.728535 -0.063,-2.62463 0.71441,1.15181 4.37994,1.49796 -4.97857,8.36746 -1.83043,5.08189 0.21949,-13.55362 z"
     id="clavicule-right" />
  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 42.200945,16.586495 -1.57473,1.56517 -0.81404,2.06905 -0.38603,2.52859 1.83679,-1.23927 2.76223,-1.15538 1.84691,3.4342 1.13679,5.49715 0.0767,5.8593 4.07066,1.10938 -0.10355,-7.94098 -1.94107,-4.90022 -5.04395,-8.19334 z"
     id="back-left" />

  <path
     style="opacity:1"
     d="m 49.625175,14.629325 0.063,-2.62462 -0.71441,1.15181 -4.37994,1.49796 4.97857,8.36746 1.83043,5.08188 -0.21949,-13.55362 z"
     id="clavicule-left" />
</svg>
    <span style="position:fixed; top:50px; left:50px">{{data_clicked_id}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use a framework lie vue to handle this. I took the liberty to copy your code to make and example. I edited a little the svgs definition to make it work.  I think the problem you could be having was with the filling of the path. fill-opacity:1 did the trick.(by the way, this is my first contribution to stackoverflow!)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Nice answer. 
A couple of things:
- Be careful answering with just "use a framework" answers, because usually users are interested in solutions aplicable for their tech stack. Your answer, IMHO, is fine, because you put effort into your answer. But it's something to take into account.

- A good practice, in case you want to improve it a little more, is to use the "Code Snippet" tool, which lets you introduce the whole working example into your answer.

Comment: didn't found how the Code Snippet option. Thats what I was aiming for, but couldn't do it that way.

Comment: No problem!.  it's on the formatting bar. The 7th icon (second group of icons from left to right, it has 2 symbols "<>" on a square). You can also use it by it's keyboard shortcut Ctrl + M

Comment: do you have this human body but separated for path? for legs? etc?, for each part.

Comment: Edited the answer svg drawing, hope it helps.

Comment: You should definitely make this into a library...I'll try and do it then link back credits to you...

Comment: Edit -> I made the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-body-part-selector. @CarlosFuentes please contact me so you can get some credit for the library.